# Do you see any way to shorten this class name?

Tags: oop, naming-conventions, naming

I have a class called `PriceStep`. I keep a list of `PriceStep` objects in a class called `PriceStepSearchSpace`. Now I am required to have different `PriceStepSearchSpace` objects for different products and I need to keep them in some sort of a dictionary. I called this new class `PriceStepSearchSpaceRepository`.

Can you think of a simpler/shorter name?

Comment: It's not the length that matters, it's how easy it is to read. Add some underscores and keep the name as descriptive as it is, i.e. `price_step_search_space`

Comment: @Inverse - Underscores make it easier to read?  I'm glad you're not writing the coding standard for my department.

Comment: @inverse - That's a matter of taste for different standards I guess. We don't use underscores except unit test names.

Comment: I think that underscores do make sentences easier to read but they are a PITA to type. Especially when trying to use code completion features of an IDE. I _do_ like to use full sentences with underscores for unit test names however since I only ever have to type them once and don't have to refer to them in other code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might call it `PriceStepSearchSpaces` if it was unlikely that I would have any other type of collection of those objects.  Otherwise, I like Timwi's idea of putting related classes into a namespace to prevent duplication of prefixes.

Answer (score 6):

You could call it `Repository` and put it in a namespace called `PriceSteps.Searchspaces`.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `SearchSpace` for your first and `SearchSpaceDictionary` for the second.

There's no need to preface a parent class with it's child class name!

However, you may want to re-think your object model, it's hard to give advice about that based on the info you provided.

Answer (score 0):

`PriceStep`. `PriceSteps`. `PriceStepsByProduct`.